# How much energy is required to make an ion?

Tags: electrons, energy, ionization-energy

So say that I have a normal hydrogen atom (not an isotope, just regular normal hydrogen atom) and I want to make it into an ion $\text{H}^+$. Since to make an ion of that formula I need to take away an electron, it is just the same as giving the electron energy for it to transition from quantum energy level 1 to level $\infty$, so I use the energy level formula for the hydrogen atom $E_n = -\frac{1312}{n^2}$ and substitute $n$ for $1$ and $\infty$ to get $-1312 \text{ kJ/mol}$ and $0\text{ kJ/mol}$ respectively. So if I add 1312 $\text{kJ/mol}$ of energy to the electron it should leave the atom, right? But my textbook says it is wrong.

Comment: What value does your textbook give?

Comment: This was actually a multiple choice question that gives a bunch of choices and asks which of these choices are correct. However, when I got to this choice and solved it out, I got the answer like above and the choice to me was correct. The textbook however, said a different choice was the correct choice.

Comment: Might be a sign error - meaning, you have to put in 1312 kJ/mol, so it would be a positive and not negative number. Was that a choice?

Comment: No, I got the answer that the choice gave, and it was positive.

Comment: I am baffled. Perhaps someone who is more knowledgeable than me will step in and set us both straight.

Comment: Is the problem that you need the energy for a **single** ion rather than a mole?

Comment: I don't think so, because 1312 kJ per mol is a lot of energy, andthe formula for an individual atom has a smaller denominator.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by smaller denominator. If the units are the same, clearly the numerator will be smaller if you're only looking at one atom rather than a mole of them. Can you calculate the energy for a single atom?